# UIPanGestureRecognizer - view dissappears on drag

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a strange problem with using UIPanGestureRecognizer to move a view from the top of the screen. Everything works perfect in simulator but on the actual device the view dissappears when I touch it.

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint start;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        start = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
        originCenter = recognizer.view.center.y;
    }

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
        if (down) {
            if (originCenter + translation.y < self.view.center.y && self.view.center.y + translation.y < self.view.center.y) {
                CGPoint move = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, originCenter-(start.y-translation.y));
                [recognizer.view setCenter:move];
            }
        }else{
            if (originCenter + translation.y < self.view.center.y && originCenter + translation.y > originCenter) {
                CGPoint move = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, originCenter-(start.y-translation.y));
                [recognizer.view setCenter:move];
            }
        }
    }

    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded  || [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ){
        if(recognizer.view.center.y > -40){

            [recognizer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

            down = TRUE;
        }else{

            [recognizer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80-self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

            down = FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

There is one thing that comes to my mind that there might be problem with calculating the position on the device and the view is moved outside the screen. Is that possible?

Comment: As an aside, you're using `down` during `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, but you don't set it until `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`. Perhaps you're initializing it elsewhere, but it's a curious construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else, you should make `start` a `static` or an ivar. Otherwise, when you hit `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, `start` will not have preserved the value it had during `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`.

Comment: Oh my god! it seems so obvious now. Thank you very much :-) Any idea why it worked in simulator but not device?

Comment: @adam I can imagine any of a number of weird compiler optimizations that would have, by pure happenstance, made it work. But but not reliably so, and I certainly never would have predicted that it would work, as the values of uninitialized variables are undefined (except objects in ARC, but CGPoint is not an object). BTW, it's quite possible that Xcode's static analyzer ("Analyze" on the "Product" menu) probably would have caught this issue. The static analyzer is a wonderful, yet under-appreciated, tool.